# Errors when I try command "make" or "Makefile" in trec_eval with Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: makefile, segmentation-fault, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I write command "make" or "Makefile" in trec_eval v 8.1 on Ubuntu Windows 10 I get this error:

```
make: gcc: Command not found
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'trec_eval' failed
make: *** [trec_eval] Error 127.
```

I tried to do this with trec eval 9, but I got this error: `segmentation fault (core dumped)` .

Comment: Can you confirm that you have gcc installed (run `gcc --version` in the shell)?  If not, you may have to `sudo apt install build-essential` to get it.

Comment: i have just install it , but now in trec eval 8.1 when i put my command ,, i get nothing ,, there is no answer :

Comment: i tryed to do this with trec eval 9 , i get this error : segmentation fault (core dumped) ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You got a `gcc: Command not found` because gcc is not currently installed in Ubuntu, so install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install make gcc
```

This installs the default version of gcc. To install a newer version of gcc run `sudo apt install gcc-8` instead.

Comment: It is quite likely that you will have additional missing dependencies. Whoever provided the `Makefile` should have provided documentation with specific requirements.

Comment: If this is the [NIST `trec_eval`](https://trec.nist.gov/trec_eval/), the tarball contains a README with this instruction: *"Installation: Should be as easy as typing "make" in the source directory, if `gcc` is available.  Otherwise, comment out the `gcc` lines (lines 5-6) and uncomment out the `cc` lines (lines 9-10)"* (Clearly they assume you have either `gcc` or a legacy `cc` already installed.)

Comment: They also assume you are in `/home/smart` for the `install` target to work so this is not really a properly packaged piece of software.